# limit results for Ask.com per URL parameter

Tags: url, search-engine, url-parameters

I'm looking for an URL parameter to set the results per page on Ask (ask.com) search engine? For Google and Bing I found a parameter, but for Ask.com I get only some results for a Web Search API, but that's not what I'm looking for. Does anyone know, if there is a parameter like num=30 or so to display X results, like:

http://de.ask.com/web?q=something&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir&num=30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out, that this is not possible. So I have to grab next page on my own.